# How to calculate the mass of air that fits into a balloon of a certain size?

Tags: gas-laws, mole

> A hot air balloon has a $\pu{500 m^3}$ volume.
>   How much mass of normal air fits into the balloon, if the relative molar mass is $\pu{28.8 g/mol}$?

I am not sure if I should simply use the $PV=nRT$ formula and therefore
$$1\times500= m/28.8 \times 273 \times 8.31 .$$

I feel that there is something wrong, can anyone enlighten me with the right formula or the basic concept of solving this kind of questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right in using the ideal gas law, but the numbers are wrong. Assuming atmospheric conditions, the pressure is 101,325 Pascal and the temperature is likely to be higher than 0°C (273 K). So the mass of the gas (in *grams*) would be:

$$m = \frac{\pu{101325 Pa} \times \pu{500 m3} \times \pu{28.8 g mol-1}}{\pu{8.31 J K-1 mol-1} \times \pu{290 K}^{[1]}}$$

where you can choose an appropriate value for <sup>[1]</sup> for your location. All values (except for the molar mass) are in SI base units, as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Common_form).